# Run feature action in WMS or ArcGIS REST server layer. Why can't I do it?

Tags: qgis

When using a WMS layer or an ArcGIS REST server layer in QGIS desktop, the actions tab is not available in the properties menu. The identify tool works with these types of layers, but I am unable to find a setting that allows me to create actions.

Comment: What part of the [documentation on actions](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html?highlight=action) makes you think this should be possible?

Comment: Is the Actions functionality only for Vector Layers? There is no mention of other types of layers in the documentation. Is the lack of an actions functionality for other types of layers just something that has not been developed yet. It seems that this would be a relatively easy functionality to develop, as I assume the existing functionality for the vector layers could be extended. I am trying to work out if it just doesn't exist yet, or if my setup somehow is blocking it.

Comment: Okay, let me rephrase the question: Which data types beside vector data (and data bases) have an attribute table? And how does the actions function work?

Comment: Im not sure of the exact technical distinction, but if I use the Identify tool on one of the polygons of the rest server layer, it returns information. It is reading a database off the cloud and returning a  set of data that then renders in the results tab. I then want to use one of these items as the basis for a google search. How can I access that bit of data. I would have preferred to use the actions functionality as it is nice and light weight, rather than having to write my own plugin that queries the server. To go back to your first question... that is exactly the point. Is it possible?

Comment: WMS and raster data has no attribute table (you can access). Period. I suggest you edit your question to rephrase it. Outline your goal, tell us what you tried (using actions) and where exactly your stuck right now (automatically retrieving info from WMS data).

Answer (score 1):

Probably it isn't possible.

> An action is something that happens when you click on a feature.

ref: https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html?highlight=action

But in a WMS you don't click on feature, you click on a map image (a picture of a feature).  The WMS GetFeatureInfo takes as input an image coordinate (a pixel) in an image, and returns a set of attributes (which may or may not include any geometry).

If it's your WMS service, you could edit the GetFeatureInfo template, so that you get a link to a Google search for an attribute name value, in the HTML response.